# Xamarin Forms localization no fall back to default resource-file

Tags: xamarin.forms, localization

I've implemented localisation based on [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=windows).

Only for languages for whom I explicitly add a resource file it is functioning as expected. For other languages I get a 'filenotfound exception'.

Moreover if I only add a default resource file it is not functioning.

UPDATE1:

```
[ContentProperty("ContentPropertyName")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    readonly CultureInfo currentCultureInfo;
    private const string ResourceId = "App.Localization.Translations";

    private static  Lazy<ResourceManager> ResMgr
    {
        get
        {
            var assembly = typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(ResourceId, assembly);
            return new Lazy<ResourceManager>(() => resourceManager);
        }
    }

    public string ContentPropertyName { get; set; }

    public TranslateExtension()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS || Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            currentCultureInfo = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        }
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (ContentPropertyName == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        // Exception thrown here
        var translation = ResMgr.Value.GetString(ContentPropertyName, currentCultureInfo);
        if (translation == null)
        {
            translation = ContentPropertyName; 
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

UPDATE2:
The Problem was temporarily solved. Earlier today the 'default' resource file was corrupted. I deleted the corrupted resource file, copied the en-GB version, renamed it to the default. Apparently this is something that VS does not like that much. I delete that new default. Create a new empty one and from the resource editor of the en-GB version I selected all rows, copied them, pasted them in the new default one, save and all works fine now.

UPDATE3:
The problem re-appeared and this trick does not help anymore.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: First of all it would be nice to see some code to help identifying the issue.

Besides that, have you tried loading your resource file within a try/catch block, then catch the FileNotFoundException and handle loading the default file after the exception was caught?

Comment: Added the code which is copy/paste from the doc-pages. The sample app from the doc-pages does load the defaults.

Comment: Did you save the new resource file as embedded file? Did you compare with the sample and find any difference? I saw there is no file called default in sample and instead it use AppResources.resx to contain the default language strings.

Comment: Resource is embedded. No differences with sample found. Is copy/paste of that code. I have a Translations.resx and a Translations.en-GB.resx. first should be the fall back, but it does not do the job. The 'funny' part is that at a certain point it did work. But when I added an extra string, that string was not 'reachable'.

Comment: I added some other strings and than it was totally messed up again. The test-phone is set in en-GB, so the solution used the Translations.en-B.resx file and that is working fine. But when I delete that file, it should use the Translations.resx, which it does not. It rather mind boggling what is going on. Already cleaned the solution, deleted all obj and bin folders, rebuild, restarted VS. No change.

Comment: You can open a free Xamarin support case and provide a sample here: [supportforXamarin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6). It's hard for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've exactly the same problem. My Resources.en.resx is reverted all the time. Resources.resx is working. Did you found a solution?